# Error "Failed to connect to the server: Timed Out", on Barrier

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have a machine with windows and one with Linux Ubuntu.

I'm trying to make the connection between both, using **Barrier** (a software that connects two machines so I can use the same mouse and keyboard on both).

I'm using Windows as Server and Linux as Client. But when I start, I can see the following WARNING message in the Client log on Linux.

**"WARNING: failed to connect to server: timed out"**

Note: When I use Linux for Server and Windows for Client it works.

**Already tried:**

-Disable Windows Firewall;

-Disable SSL on both Barries;

-I already uncommented #WaylandEnable=false.

Comment: Have you checked that all Barrier Windows process are working? See https://github-wiki-see.page/m/albertony/barrier/wiki/Troubleshooting . Also, I'd suggest turning Windows Firewall *on*, opening only connections for the Barrier's processes.

Comment: I opened the barrie process connections, but it still didn't work, do you know what I should do??

Answer (score 0):

You can check this, hope you will find it helpful: https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/193

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241257)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).